# php update - centos 7 failed

Tags: php, centos, centos7, php-5.6

I have Centos 7 server running apache 2.4.48 and php 5.6.40 I'm trying to update php to 7X on my server but am having some issues.

```sh
entered into XXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                                                    
[root@XXXXXXXXXX /]# sudo yum install epel-release yum-utils                                                    
-bash: sudo: command not found                                                                               
[root@XXXXXXX /]# yum install epel-release yum-utils                                                         
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror                                                                                
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile                                                                   
 * base: ftp.icm.edu.pl                                                                                      
 * epel: ftp.icm.edu.pl                                                                                      
 * extras: ftp.icm.edu.pl                                                                                    
 * remi-php72: mirror.23media.com                                                                            
 * remi-php73: mirror.23media.com                                                                            
 * remi-safe: mirror.23media.com                                                                             
 * updates: ftp.icm.edu.pl                                                                                   
Package epel-release-7-13.noarch already installed and latest version                                        
Package yum-utils-1.1.31-54.el7_8.noarch already installed and latest version                                
Nothing to do                                                                                                
[root@vz12160 /]# yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm                         
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror                                                                                
remi-release-7.rpm                                                                    |  23 kB  00:00:00     
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-Kw5P4D/remi-release-7.rpm: remi-release-7.9-1.el7.remi.noarch                    
/var/tmp/yum-root-XXXXX/remi-release-7.rpm: does not update installed package.                              
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Nothing to do

There is no error here, remi-release is already installed, as stated by the repo list:

> - remi-php72: mirror.23media.com
> - remi-php73: mirror.23media.com
> - remi-safe: mirror.23media.com

For proper configuration, follow the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

Comment: I did everything according to the Wizard but I still got php 5.6 .

Comment: So not enough information in your question... rpm -qa \*php\* .... which php ...

Comment: yum update  then i got No packages marked for update

Comment: again, not enough information about how PHP 5.6 was installed.

Comment: I'm sorry but unfortunately I don't know how it was installed :( the specialist who installed php is unreachable.

Comment: as in previous comment... rpm -qa | grep php .... which php ..

Comment: login as: console-xxxxxxxxxx
console-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxs password:
entered into xxxxxxxxxxxxx
[root@xxxxxxxxxxx /]# which php
/usr/local/bin/php
[root@xxxxxxx /]# rpm -qf $(which php)
file /usr/local/bin/php is not owned by any package
[root@xxxxxxxxxxx]# rpm -qa | grep php
[root@xxxxxx]#
Sorry for late response.

Comment: So this is a manually build from sources PHP. RPM cannot update such installation. You have to do a proper installation.

Comment: May I ask how to do a proper instalation? Is there perhaps a tutorial on how to do this? Thank You.

Comment: From a fresh system, following the wizard instructions ;)

Comment: Installing a fresh system is not for me, I am not an expert.If I upgrade from centos 7 to centos 8 can I change PHP ?

Comment: upgrade from centos 7 to centos 8 is always a fresh install.